# read socket data with java

Tags: java, javascript, sockets

i'm using websocket to send data, this is the code (javascript)

```
  socket= new WebSocket('ws://localhost:10302/socket');
                      socket.onopen= function() {
                          socket.send('delete structure'+c);
                      }
```

in the server side i'm using java and this is the code

```
try {
        standardiste = new ServerSocket(10302);
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("listening data from socket");
            socket = standardiste.accept();
            try {

                BufferedReader  entree = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                while(entree!=null)
                {

                System.out.println(entree.readLine());
                }
            }
            catch(IOException exc) {
            }
            socket.close();
        }
    }
```

i want to read the data sended ?

Comment: Your server code indicates that you don't know even the very basic of the WebSocket Protocol ([RFC 6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455)). You should learn it before starting coding. Basically, you should select and use a server-side solution which supports the WebSocket Protocol. [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/) and [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-server-api.html), for example.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

```
String line;
while((line = entree.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

What you were trying was to tie in the BufferedReader into the Socket, but never read anything from it. That's where the BufferedReader.readLine() method comes in, which reads a single line (until it reaches an endline character) from the buffer.

By comparing the current line to null (`readLine() != null`) you keep reading until it stops receiving the end of a transmission.

**Edit:**

I'm afraid the WebSocket protocol is different from the Java Socket protocol, hence it receives just the headers, but doesn't recognize any of the actual data that is being sent, simple because the protocols don't match up. Try using the Java WebSocket class. Here is a good tutorial.

Comment: with this code i get many information but not the data sended with socket

Comment: i get :   GET /socket HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10302
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,ar;q=0.4
Sec-WebSocket-Key: aPjFF7FlQqh879tJD8d+hg==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits

Comment: The way you're doing it, given that you fixed it the way I suggested, is the most common way to read data from a socket. So it must be something on the JavaScript end. Perhaps you could give some more context? Or elaborate on what the `c` variable is you're passing with the socket in the JavaScript code snippet.

Comment: it's not problem to send c variable. i want just to recive data from client socket ????  my code give me other information

Comment: I'm not saying there is a problem with the `c` variable, I am just curious about what you're trying to send, since there might be a catch somewhere.

Comment: i want to send simple string ("hello") but i'm not able get it ?   the data sended with websocket ena reading from java class

Comment: I'm afraid the WebSocket protocol is different from the Java Socket protocol, hence it receives just the headers, but doesn't recognize any of the actual data that is being sent, simple because the protocols don't match up. Try using the Java WebSocket class. [Here](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api/) is a good tutorial.